# when click in image it become bigger and on centre of screen

Tags: asp.net, html

---

Hello,
I am working on a project where user upload images and I want that when user click on image it become bigger on full screen and at the centre of the screen how can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
 <img src="@Model.Pic1" class="img-responsive" width="750" height="750"/> <img src="@Model.Pic2" class="img-responsive" width="750" height="750"/> <img src="@Model.Pic3" class="img-responsive" width="750" height="750"/> <img src="@Model.Pic4" class="img-responsive" width="750" height="750"/> <img src="@Model.Pic5" class="img-responsive" width="750" height="750"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried lot of zoom effect but i think which i want now is best

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed;` to make an elements position relative to the viewpoint.

Then use `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center it. (this will position the top left corner in the middle of the screen, but then moves it -50%, -50% relative to image size so that it then is centered.)

To change states simply create one CSS-selector for the normal position and one centered and toggle the second class via JS. (using `element.classList.toggle("centeredStyle");`)

Note that since you change the positioning of your image from presumably static to fixed that will rearrange your other elements (because elements with `position: fixed;` don't take up space). To stop that, you can simply wrap all images and always resize the wrapper instead of the image itself.